# How to change the shape of the one column header when hover? in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular-material

This CSS happens when the user starts dragging, then it shows the box which is cool. What I want to achieve is when hover one column, I want to just draw the box show effects of shadows, so that users can recognize that this column is draggable. 
How do I achieve that? 
Hover over one column header, show some effects of shadows in Angular Material Table.

```
.cdk-drag-preview {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

Comment: Regardless of Angular, the CSS for hover action is, well, `:hover`. So `th:hover {...show hover eye-candy... }` or fill in some `.column-class` for `th`. This seems easy enough...

Comment: But how can I select a one column header only, which is just a box of one th

Comment: For a proper answer I will need to see more code with HTML/CSS, post a [reprex]...